# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException within Hardcoded Bounds

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

Working on an assignment where I am supposed to read in data from a file into an array to do some search/sort demonstrations.

```
public class A5 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
     fileToArray();
}
 /**
 * populates array from file
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws FileNotFoundException
 */
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void fileToArray() throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
    int FileIndex = 0;

    A5GItem[] gItems = new A5GItem[5150];
        File file = new File("GroceryData.txt");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);


        while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
                String line = inputFile.nextLine().replace(" oz", "").replace("«", "");

            String[] tokens = line.split(";");
            if (tokens.length == 5) {

            System.out.println(tokens[0]);
            System.out.println(tokens[1]);
            System.out.println(tokens[2]);
            System.out.println(tokens[3]);
            System.out.println(tokens[4]);
            System.out.println(FileIndex);

            FileIndex++;
            else {
                System.out.println("Bad line: " + line);} 
                        }   }`
```

I tried to test whether I had filled the array properly by looping some println statements. It properly tokenizes the first 400(roughly) elements in the list and then only prints half of the last token and throws

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at A5.fileToArray(A5.java:59)
    at A5.main(A5.java:16)`

after having run through with that index for many iterations. Not sure where to begin troubleshooting.

Comment: `tokens = line.split(";");`: that doesn't seem hard-coded...

Comment: It was my assumption that the line above it set the bounds given that there are never more than 5 tokens

Comment: Take care of java naming convention. Variable names must start with lower case characters.

Comment: Print `line` directly, that should be a good start in troubleshooting this issue

Comment: What are you using FileIndex for? Since you are using a Scanner, the hasNext is going line by line. And as @Jens wrote: camel-case notation. No variable starting with an upper case. And what is line 59 in your case?

Comment: @AlexanderFalk I was using that variable for some later steps I left out populating a generic array with the tokens

Comment: Initializing tokens to `tokens = new String[5];` is redundant and will not ensure that your tokens array will have five elements. Rather you should write `if (tokens.length == 5) { do your stuff } else { System.out.println("Bad line: " + line)}`

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Updated. I'm still not able to find what separated that line of the file from the next. The line in question is  `Beech-Nut Stage 2;Mixed Vegetables;4 oz;5.67;6047` where the last token ends on `Vegeta`. The list before that looks like `Beech-Nut Stage 2;Pears & Pineapple;4 oz;7.27;6031
Beech-Nut Stage 2;Pears & Raspberries;4 oz;8.83;5731
Beech-Nut Stage 2;Butternut Squash;4 oz;1.39;5932
Beech-Nut Stage 2;Corn & Sweet Potatoes;4 oz;5.12;5796
Beech-Nut Stage 2;Country Garden Vegetables;4 oz;10.04;6046` for comparrison

Answer (score 0):

Obviously one of the lines in file "GroceryData.txt" does not contain 5 tokens. Note that method `split()` returns an array whose size may not be 5. So initializing the variable `tokens` is not necessary. It seems that variable `FileIndex` counts the lines read, so I suggest printing it as well as printing the size of array `tokens` after the `split()`, e.g.

```
while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
    String line = inputFile.nextLine().replace(" oz", "").replace("«", "");
    String[] tokens = line.split(";");
    FileIndex++;
    System.out.println("Line: " + FileIndex + " has " + tokens.length + " tokens.");
}
```

Then you will discover which line of the file is not as you expect it to be.

By the way, regarding the naming convention that the commenters mention, it's just that - a convention. It's not what's causing your `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Also the stack trace you posted indicates that line 59 of your code contains the problem. I believe that would be this line...

```
System.out.println(tokens[2]);
```

Printing the elements of the array presumes it contains 5 elements, but as I and others have mentioned, method `split()` may not return a 5 element array.

Comment: First try what I suggested. You need to debug your code and not just walk through it. What I suggested is a simple way to locate what may be causing the `Exception`.

Comment: Finding the line causing the exception was not an issue, i posted it an above comment. The line was  `Beech-Nut Stage 2;Mixed Vegetables;4 oz;5.67;6047`  which i don't see what's different about it from the previous lines `Beech-Nut Stage 2;Pears;4 oz;2.95;5925
Beech-Nut Stage 2;Pears & Pineapple;4 oz;7.27;6031
Beech-Nut Stage 2;Pears & Raspberries;4 oz;8.83;5731
Beech-Nut Stage 2;Butternut Squash;4 oz;1.39;5932
Beech-Nut Stage 2;Country Garden Vegetables;4 oz;10.04;6046`. The last token ends on `Vegata` having already split the string vegetables multiple time without issue

Comment: You located the bad line, but do you know why it's bad? Apparently it doesn't contain 5 tokens. Do you know how many tokens `split()` returned for that line? Also, which line from the original code you posted is line 59?

Comment: 2 `Beech-Nut Stage 2` and
 `Mixed Vegeta`. Line 59 would have been   `System.out.println(tokens[2]);`

Comment: That doesn't look like java code. I meant line 59 of your java code. If you are using an IDE, like _Eclipse_, there should be a link in the stack trace that will take you directly to that line in your code.

Comment: Posted the first half of the response before the line of code. That bit was from the file. Hard to beat the enter muscle memory on this sites comments

Comment: removing the line `Beech-Nut Stage 2;Mixed Vegetables;4 oz;5.67;6047` and the code ran without error. I just can't figure out what is different about that line

Comment: Exactly what I suspected. The `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is because `tokens` contains only two elements. You need to scrutinize that line. Perhaps print out the characters using method `toCharArray()` of class `java.lang.String`.

Comment: When i cut and pasted the line back into the file after removing it that line seems to run properly now. My guess is the professor included some special character as an edge case that got stripped in the copy paste